# Tricky xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath and xml parsing in general. I read some documentations but couldn't find a solution for my problem. My .xml looks like this (fyi: it's the playlist part of "iTunes Music Library.xml"):

```
    <dict>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>Name</key><string>Playlist 1</string>
          <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>187826</integer>
          <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>04250E0617138909</string>
          <key>All Items</key><true/>
          <key>Playlist Items</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>Track ID</key><integer>11111</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>Track ID</key><integer>22222</integer>
            </dict>
          </array
        </dict>
        <dict>
          <key>Name</key><string>Playlist 2</string>
          <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>187826</integer>
          <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>04250E0617138909</string>
          <key>All Items</key><true/>
          <key>Playlist Items</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>Track ID</key><integer>23456</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>Track ID</key><integer>34567</integer>
            </dict>
          </array
        </dict>
      </dict>
```

My input is a string containing the name of a playlist. Now here is what I want for my output: All songIDs related to that specific playlist. Unfortunately the name is not an attribute of for example *array* or that first *dict*. Here's what I've got (java-code):

```
ap.selectXPath("//dict/array/dict/string[1][text()=\"" + playlistName + "\"]");
```

That just gives me my playlistName of course. So how to proceed from now on? This came to my mind: Parse the file like this until the parser reaches the desired name:

```
ap.selectXPath("//dict/array/dict[" + count++ +"]/string[1]");
```

with an "int count". Then start again from that position with an appropriate query. Then again, this doesn't seem to be elegant or efficient.

Long story short: is there a XPath query to fulfill my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a `dict` element works in the plist format is alternating pairs of elements, with each value being the first following sibling element of its `key`.  So for a given key you can access the value as

```
key[. = 'Entry name']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

So for the particular example you're interested in, the `dict` element for "Playlist 1" is

```
/dict/array/dict[key[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::*[1] = 'Playlist 1']
```

its track listing `array` is

```
/dict/array/dict[key[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::*[1] = 'Playlist 1']
  /key[. = 'Playlist Items']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

and then the set of `integer` elements giving the track IDs would be

```
/dict/array/dict[key[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::*[1] = 'Playlist 1']
  /key[. = 'Playlist Items']/following-sibling::*[1]
  /dict/key[. = 'Track ID']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Be careful if you're getting the playlist names from user input and they might contain single or double quote characters.  You don't say what library you're using, but if it supports defining variables then you should use that mechanism to inject your values rather than relying on string concatenation to build up your expressions.